# ¿Como mostrar correo de cuentas de Google logeadas en mi app Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, email, show

estaba haciendo una aplicación online en Android Studio conectada a Firebase, y el tema es que quería hacer una lista de todos los participantes logeados desde Google en mi app. He buscado código y he encontrado gente que muestra los correos de la gente logeada directamente en la aplicación, pero mi objetivo es mostrar, los correos de la gente que se logea con la cuenta de google , en un List view y no consigo hacerlo.

Tengo la aplicación configurada y conectada a Firebase, y a su vez Firebase configurado para que se pueda logear mediante Google.

Hasta ahora, he conseguido realizar un login y cuando accedes te muestra información sobre tu perfil, pero me gustaría que al acceder te apareciese un ListView con el nombre o el correo o algún dato de los que están logeados en la aplicación y online.

Con este código muestro la información personal de cada usuario:

```
 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

            nameTextView.setText(account.getDisplayName());
            emailTextView.setText(account.getEmail());
            idTextView.setText(account.getId());
            Glide.with(this).load(account.getPhotoUrl()).into(photoImageView);

        } else {
            goLogInScreen();
        }
    }
```

Y mi objetivo es mostrar esta información en los dispositivos de otras personas. Me podrían ayudar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la información de perfil recuperada de los proveedores de acceso vinculados con un usuario, usa el método `getProviderData()`

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        // Id del proveedor (ex: google.com)
        String providerId = profile.getProviderId();

        // UID especifico del proveedor
        String uid = profile.getUid();

        // Nombre, E-mail y Foto de perfil
        String name = profile.getDisplayName();
        String email = profile.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
    }
}
```

Al loopear sobre `getProviderData()` nuestro `profile.getProviderId()` nos va a devolver si esta logueado con google, si es asi, debajo deberias obtener la informacion de ese usuario y almacenarlo en algun nodo aparte por ejemplo : `Usuarios_Conectados` , y luego haces un fetch de ese nodo y lo pones en un listview, de esa forma vas a tener una lista de solo los usuarios logueados con google en tu app.

Pudes obtener mas información de los siguientes links

- [Providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information)
- [getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderData())
- [getProviderId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderId())

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, intentaré hacerlo como dices a ver qué resultado me da, cuando lo realice te cuento.